# App Store on MacOS Lion doesnt load

Tags: macos, itunes, mac-appstore

Since a while now, I can't use the app store anymore on my MacOS Lion.
It just keeps the screen "One Moment Please. Connecting to the iTunes Store.".

I tried a couple of things ... rebootet ... waitet for days and tried it again ... cleared the cache, as described here: [Mountain Lion Doesn't Download from Store](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59998/mountain-lion-doesnt-download-from-store) and some more stuff.

Nothing shows up in the Console.app ... iTunes works just fine ...

The only thing that's curiouse is, that if I click on the link "To download iTunes, please click here.", the page shown is in swedish ... I've never chosen that as language on this system.

**EDIT:**
The login doesn't work. The credentials are correct, because I can log in at apples developers area and download stuff like xcode from there.

Comment: Just how do you get to apple developer without logging in to apple store?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Logging in at https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/index.action just works. But it does not work if I try it using the AppStore.

Comment: Did you try to log out from apple store.

Comment: @Buscar웃 How can I signout? Or turn the question around: Is it possible to sign in if you are already? I just see the "Sign In ..." and "Create Account" actions in the menu.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Since you made your edit my answer is not valid.

In Apple store click on Store + View my Account

Sign in.

Bottom right just below the DONE click on the globe flag icon, and change to your country.

[image]

Comment: The signin doesn't work as well ... no logging here either ...